# haproxy returns error 503 service unavailable

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to configure a simple haproxy configuration to forward any request for "https://server:443/*" to "https://server:7002"  The proxy and webserver are both on the same server.  I simply want the users to be able to use the default port rather than specify 7002.

It's very straight forward.  The only thing worth mentioning is both the webserver and haproxy are using self signed ssl certificates.  I search the internet to see if that could cause an issue but I didn't find anything.

Here is the configuration I'm using:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
mode                    http
log                     global
option                  httplog
option                  dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
option                  redispatch
retries                 3
timeout http-request    10s
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         10s
timeout client          1m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check           10s
maxconn                 3000


frontend main
bind :443 ssl no-sslv3 crt /etc/haproxy/server.pem    
http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc  }
default_backend server



backend server
server   app 127.0.0.1:7002
```

I've tried a number of configurations but the error is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your `server` line tells haproxy to connect with HTTP, not HTTPS, so you get error. Try adding `ssl` to enable SSL connection to backend and `ca-file /path/to/ca/cert` so you can verify connection or `verify none` as a proof of concept.

```
server   app 127.0.0.1:7002 ssl ca-file /path/to/ca.cert
```

or

```
server   app 127.0.0.1:7002 ssl verify none
```

Comment: I tried the second option but the same error occured:

server   app 127.0.0.1:7002 ssl verify none

Comment: in that case add some logs from haproxy with sample errors to your question and verify that your backend actually works